# Case Function Returns Null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following input data(A sample only):

| ListID | date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-10-17 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-10-17 | 43.050430504 |
| 3 | 2022-10-17 | 40.000000000 |
| 4 | 2022-10-17 | 38.636363636 |
| 5 | 2022-10-17 | 20.714285714 |

I am little bit confused about two below query results.

First Query:

```
SELECT
    ListID,
    CASE 
        WHEN date>'2022-07-22' 
            THEN avg(value)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS 'Value_Before_Rate_Change'
FROM 
    TB01 where date like '2022%' and ListID=1;
```

Output first query:

| Value_Before_Rate_Change |
| --- |
| NULL |

---

Second Query

```
select avg(value)  
from TB01 
where date like '2022%' 
  and ListID=1 
  and date>'2022-07-22';
```

Output second query:

| avg(value) |
| --- |
| 57.773696518595 |

Can someone show me why I am always getting NULL as an result when I use `CASE`.

Update:

I used below group by as well. But same result

```
SELECT
        ListID,
        CASE 
            WHEN date>'2022-07-22' 
                THEN avg(value)
            ELSE NULL
        END AS 'Value_Before_Rate_Change'
    FROM 
        TB01 where date like '2022%' and ListID=1 group by ListID;
```

Comment: The 1st query is incorrect, it contains implicit incomplete GROUP BY. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and ensure. *why I am always getting NULL* Because row which is processed the most first does not match a condition.

Comment: @Akina I tried to by using group by ListID at the end, but same result.

Comment: Try getting the `AVG` aggregate function out of the `CASE` scope (in addition to akina's suggestion).

Comment: Have you enabled above SQL mode setting? do it then edit your query until it become correct. Firstly..

Comment: *Output second query* This is not possible - average is greater than the greatest value..

Comment: @Akina, due to a reason I could not change mysql settings at the moment. Further input data here shown is a sample data..Not the whole set.Sorry for confusing

Comment: *due to a reason I could not change mysql settings at the moment.* There not exists any reason which does not allow to execute `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   listID
        ,avg(case when date > '2022-07-22' then value end) as Value_Before_Rate_Change
from     t
group by listID
```

| listID | Value_Before_Rate_Change |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0000000000000000 |
| 1 | 43.0504305040000000 |
| 3 | 40.0000000000000000 |
| 4 | 38.6363636360000000 |
| 5 | 20.7142857140000000 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KFUwHCPD)